# Android, where to put my own Bluetooth class

Tags: android, code-organization

Well, I'm at a dilemma here. I made my own class that uses the Bluetooth class from android but I'm not sure where to put it. Extending the android Bluetooth class seems like a good idea but I need to override the onActivityResult() which is only available to an activity class. So, where would I put my class so that I have access to onActivityResult() (keeping in mind the idea here is to use as few dependencies as possible)?

In other words, I want to move the Bluetooth code from the main activity to a separate class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should to use separate file for each class. You can create a folder "engine". For example: `com.mycorp.myapp.engine`. You can get access to `onActivityResult()` very simple. For example: `MainActivity.onActivityResult()`. Note: function should be `public`.
Or you can pass your activity to your CustomBluetooth's constructor.

```
public class CustomBluetooth {

    private Activity mActivity;

    /* Constructor */
    public CustomBluetooth (Activity pActivity ) {
        super();
        this.mActivity = pActivity;
    }

    /* Your functions */
    public int getResult() {
        return this.mActivity.onActivityResult();
    }
}
```

Alex. P.S. Sorry for my English:)

Comment: Ah, cool, I already did something similar but I didn't know you could call the onActivityResult() like that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add an interface to your Bluetooth class and implement the interface in your activity.

Comment: You mean the other way around?